# Graffiti CMS plugin post to Facebook users wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, post, graffiticms

I want to create a plugin for Graffiti CMS that automatically sends to Facebook my post when i finish to publish it. There is any way to connect to facebook with the user's username and password and post the new content to the user's wall?

I read about the .net library that microsoft released for facebook but all auth is made by poping a window to the facebook app and i don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a set of Social Networking plugins for Graffiti.  Right now, they support Facebook and Twitter.  Source code and binaries can be found at http://graffiticmssocial.codeplex.com/.  Also, there is a discussion thread about them at http://graffiticms.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=84038.

If you decide to use them, I would appreciate any feedback you can provide, especially on the instructions for setting up Facebook to make it work - it's kind of tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the core Facebook supports a "ping" type model like that, at least not yet.

There are a variety Facebook applications however that will add posts from a RSS feed, however there would be a small delay since it would be polling. There *may* be Facebook applications that would support that type of scenario (a Graffiti plugin notifying it in real time), or you could write one.

Comment: Thank you :) i'll take it into suggestion :)